# mapping redux state to props not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

trying for first time redux on a react-native app and i have this problem...

after i connect the component , and pass a mapStateToProps call, inside the function i can log the state perfectly fine. But, when i use this prop in the component its undefined. I am using the redux state in other component just fine...

Thks!

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Content, Button, 
Text,Card,CardItem,Body,Icon,Header,Left,Right,Title  } from 'native-base';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
    };

    tryLogout(){
         console.log(this.props.isLogged);
         // UNDEFINED HERE
   }

   render() { 

     return (
       <Container>
         <Header>
           <Left></Left>
           <Body>
             <Title>Menu</Title>
           </Body>
           <Right>
             <Button transparent onPress={this.tryLogout}>
               <Icon name='menu' />
             </Button>
           </Right>
         </Header>
         <Content padder>                  
         </Content>
       </Container>
     );
   }
 }

 const mapStateToProps = state => {
   console.log(state.isLogged);
   // I GET DATA HERE
   return {
       isLogged: state.isLogged
   }
 }

 export default connect(mapStateToProps,{})(HomeScreen);
```

Comment: Your code should be working fine. Just trying luck randomly, mind to share the `combineReducers` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you are calling `this.tryLogout`, the `this` keyword is dynamically binded to the event instead of the `component` itself, so the event doesn't have the prop that you are looking for.

You can take different approaches on how to solve this:

**Using named arrow functions**

```
tryLogout = () => console.log(this.props)
...
onPress={this.tryLogout}
```

**Using the `bind` method**

`onPress={this.tryLogout.bind(this)}`

**Using inline arrow functions**

`onPress={() => this.tryLogout()}`.

You can take a look to the different techniques in the docs: [How do I bind a function to a component instance?](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance)

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving this error because your `tryLogout()` isn't binded to your component. So, the `this` reference isn't of your component. Change the declaration to this:

```
tryLogout = () => {
     console.log(this.props.isLogged);
}
```

The `() => {}` , known as `arrow function`, does the bind for you.

**TIP:**

If you build a method for your component that needs to access any `prop` or `state`, you'll need to bind the function to the component class. When you declare the method as I did above, you're binding it. So, your method will have the possibility to access any `prop` or `state` of your component.